# javaml accuracy same for all classes (only with my data)?

Tags: java, machine-learning

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
        Dataset data = FileHandler.loadDataset(new File("iris.txt"), 50, ",");
        Dataset evalData = FileHandler.loadDataset(new File("irisfull.txt"), 50, ",");
        Classifier knn = new KNearestNeighbors(5);
        knn.buildClassifier(data);

        Map<Object, PerformanceMeasure> pm = EvaluateDataset.testDataset(knn, evalData);

        for(Object o:pm.keySet())
            System.out.println(o+": "+pm.get(o).getAccuracy());
    }
```

Greetings! I am writing a school assignment on machine learning (i am in no way a professional in the field).I use javaml library. This code works on classic iris.txt just fine (accuracy approx 0.97). But, whenever I insert my data into the iris.txt (and also change classindex 4->50), the PerformanceMeasure seems to malfunction and print out accuracy of "one" as both "one" and "two" (or vice versa).

Example of my data (30 samples like this in total)

```
130.27, -80.63, 112.97, 0.0, 89.73, 134.14, -79.52, 114.29, 0.0, 87.65, 130.69, -79.58, 112.17, 0.0, 84.22, 126.9, -80.08, 106.0, 0.0, 86.2, 133.16, -79.82, 113.72, 0.0, 92.88, 132.13, -81.05, 113.49, 0.0, 97.74, 124.16, -80.69, 109.18, 0.0, 91.62, 133.31, -80.36, 116.82, 0.0, 91.66, 139.03, -78.47, 117.62, 0.0, 88.47, 143.13, -79.44, 125.02, 0.0, 96.97,one
-67.15, -83.81, 147.47, 0.0, 87.53, -72.51, -84.21, 146.45, 0.0, 96.33, -67.69, -84.44, 147.6, 0.0, 84.96, -67.05, -84.87, 144.97, 0.0, 83.52, -69.23, -84.06, 146.3, 0.0, 77.51, -68.91, -84.5, 144.07, 0.0, 87.87, -71.96, -84.45, 143.12, 0.0, 73.64, -70.94, -84.73, 143.75, 0.0, 74.4, -73.52, -84.52, 144.33, 0.0, 83.48, -62.95, -84.37, 144.5, 0.0, 102.88,one
-110.14, -80.15, 117.75, 0.0, 75.46, -111.92, -80.34, 119.03, 1.0, 77.11, -111.43, -80.2, 117.21, 0.0, 83.65, -110.17, -80.78, 117.98, 0.0, 80.38, -113.83, -79.49, 117.43, 1.0, 88.4, -113.36, -80.15, 117.56, 1.0, 85.62, -106.62, -81.3, 122.5, 0.0, 81.89, -103.48, -81.09, 124.99, 1.0, 87.83, -125.0, -78.76, 107.75, 1.0, 86.06, -109.81, -80.96, 114.7, 1.0, 79.33,one
-178.84, 72.82, 83.53, 0.0, 109.74, -80.39, 79.98, -13.35, 0.0, 108.66, 77.19, 76.98, 124.21, 0.0, 109.65, 74.66, 80.59, 166.15, 0.0, 103.41, -100.05, 80.53, 22.57, 0.0, 105.92, -12.87, 71.55, -98.41, 0.0, 105.81, 65.87, 73.04, 108.27, 0.0, 109.67, 61.01, 82.37, 178.77, 0.0, 104.66, 46.63, 67.01, -165.75, 0.0, 105.96, -150.4, 84.58, 44.67, 0.0, 107.9,two
25.83, 47.49, -21.31, 0.0, 98.99, 75.19, 67.47, -76.54, 0.0, 99.37, 19.34, -25.5, -63.96, 0.0, 95.48, 74.99, 83.5, -46.41, 0.0, 91.97, -7.61, 55.46, -144.28, 0.0, 100.24, -8.78, 24.74, -119.22, 0.0, 109.09, -26.2, 72.37, -176.77, 0.0, 109.73, -10.25, -8.74, -132.55, 0.0, 105.29, -95.8, 84.23, 27.79, 0.0, 104.68, 24.33, 65.22, -168.3, 0.0, 105.44,two
```

The main problem is the fact that I can delete all but one instances of "two", and It will show both "two" and "one" accuracy as the same (around 0.87). Furthermore, It very seldom works to separate data "one" from data "two" if I'm not taking samples from the provided database.

Please help, very important assignment.
Thank you in advance.